# Concurrent State Diagram

Tags: uml

please, help me to understand this picture 
 please, what is the explanation of this process
difference between authorizing and checking

[image: Concurrent State Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "difference". It's just that these two states exist independently of each other at the same time. E.g. when `Rejected` the whole SM ends exceptionally. It will further end and transfer to `Delivered` after `Dispatching` **and** `Authorize` have passed, no matter in which order any of these occurred.